# Regex for specific pattern and group issue

Tags: regex

using regex on golang and having hard time to group three names from the following statements:

*Hello Planet Earth 2022 - R1 3 Hell John v Tom v Ford*

*Hello World 2022 - R2 3 Hell - John v Tom v Ford*

I'm trying to group "John" "Tom" "Ford" with the following regex:

```
^(?i).+? . R\d 3 Hell (.+?)[,|v] (.+?)[,|v] (.+?)$
```

The issue is that it groups "- John"  for second statement and I need "John" only.

Any ideas how can it be adjusted?

thanks

Comment: Please format the question to be more readable (use code blocks). Also show, do not describe, the results and what you are expecting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how correct it is, but having tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/3R6t5S/1), I came up with this...

```
^(?i).+? . R\d 3 Hell[\s-]* (.+?)[,v] (.+?)[,v] (.+?)$
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, amazing, just needed to escape it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @c00l2nas It is already escaped properly. In Go, just use backticks to define the raw string literal.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to match single spaces, you can optionally match a dash and a space.

Note that the last `.+` does not have to be non greedy as it is the last part of the pattern, and the character class `[,v]` does not need a pipe char if you do not intent to match that as a character.

```
^(?i).+? . R\d 3 Hell (?:- )?(.+?) [,v] (.+?)[,v] (.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gTbhzy/1)